# apigee overwriting the target.url with a custom variable

Tags: variable-assignment, apigee

I have been trying to overwrite the target.url with a variable using the Assign Message Policy.  Per other solutions, I have put this in the "Target EndPoint" Section. The issue is, unless I hard-code the root section of the URL, the substitution fails.  I have tried all the commented VALUE stmts below with  and then started adding the "REF"stmts to attempt to solve the issue - to no avail.  You can see I have tried cutting the target into various snippets using Extract policies, but cannot get a solution that works.

Thanks for help.

For the purposes of the code snippet below

```
entireURL = "http://my.root.url/thestuff/morestuff"
AppServerURL = "my.root.url/thestuff/morestuff"
AppServerRoot = "my.root.url"
AppServerSfx = "thestuff/morestuff"
```

codee from Assign Message Policy

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<AssignMessage async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="Post-to-named-serverL">
    <DisplayName>Post to named server</DisplayName>
    <FaultRules/>
    <Properties/>
    <AssignVariable>
          <Name>target.url</Name>
          <Value>http://${AppServerRoot}/{AppServerSfx}</Value>
          <Ref/>
          <!--
            <Value>http://my.root.url/{AppServerSfx}</Value>  works but I need the root changed
            <Value>http://{AppServerRoot}/{AppServerSfx}</Value>
            <Value>http://${AppServerRoot}/{AppServerSfx}</Value>
            <Value>http://{AppServerURL}</Value>
            <Value>http://${AppServerURL}</Value>
            <Value>entireURL</Value>
            <Value>{entireURL}</Value>  -- this was my first try
            <Value>${entireURL}</Value>
            <Ref>entireURL</Ref>
            <Ref>{entireURL}</Ref>
            <Ref>${entireURL}</Ref>
          -->
    </AssignVariable>
    <IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>false</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>
    <AssignTo createNew="false" transport="http" type="request"/>
</AssignMessage>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are correctly putting the `target.url` manipulation in the Target Request flow.

Using `AssignMessage/AssignVariable` can be limiting. The `Value` element doesn't allow you to do any variable substitutions.

The following worked for me:

```
<Ref>entireURL</Ref>
```

`Ref` also doesn't allow variable substitutions -- it just takes the name of the variable. Since you have to build the value of that variable ahead of time, using the `Ref` example above doesn't buy you much.

I usually accomplish target URL rewriting using a JavaScript callout with code similar to the following:

```
var appServerRoot = context.getVariable("AppServerRoot");
var appServerSfx = context.getVariable("AppServerSfx");
context.setVariable("target.url", "http://" + appServerRoot + "/" + appServerSuffix);
```

Comment: Thanks using <Ref> as described worked fine. I thought I had tried that per my post above, but it is good to have it documented.  FYI, VALUE does allow variable substitution as described in the training session week 3.  That is why I went down that road.  Thanks again.

Comment: I might be wrong (I'm recalling this from a while ago), but I think if you check the value of the variable after using Value, I think it generally will show exactly the string you put in it (no variable substitution done). I seem to remember that I thought that variable substitution was being done in the AssignMessage, but it was during a later use of the variable (maybe ServiceCallout/HTTPTargetConnection/URL) that the substitution actually occurred.

Comment: If you look at the week 3 lesson 8 video, and go to 6:38 in the video, you'll see in the Variables Set section that the {jokeid} variable has not been replaced with 3229 during the AssignMessage. It is only later, when the target.url is used, that the replacement happens.